# NSMutableDictionary & JSONRepresentation

Tags: ios, json, frameworks

I download the framework JSON, add to my project, i think it is correctly add because when i put

```
#import <JSON/JSON.h>
```

i don't have any warning. But when i want to use it, the matter is started :

```
NSMutableDictionary * attachement = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *requestJson = [attachement JSONRepresentation];
```

But i have a warning on JSONRepresentation :

```
Instance method '-JSONRepresentation' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

How can i fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm thinking you must also import a category header file -- something like "NSDictionary+JSON.h".  It should have been included with the framework.

Comment: It's not included in the framework :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're on iOS 5.0 and up, use the built in `NSJSONSerialization`

```
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:attachement 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
    //Deal with error
} else {
    NSString *requestJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: ROOOOOH "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: app_id)'
"...

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you're inserting a nil object into an NSMutableDictionary.